# What is NonDynamicallyQuantizableLinear?

Tags: python, pytorch

I found NonDynamicallyQuantizableLinear while reading torch.nn.modules.activation.py in MultiheadAttention class
And I have a few questions about it

1. What is the difference between Linear and NonDynamicallyQuantizableLinear?
2. Why is NonDynamicallyQuantizableLinear used for MultiheadAttention?

Comment: It's a [work around](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/nn/modules/linear.py#L122) to avoid an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is introduced as a temporary cleanup measure to fail immediately when attempting directly quantize `torch.nn.MultiheadAttention`. This improves upon the baseline behavior of failing silently.

See https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/58969